# Отправка формы аяксом

Tags: jquery, jquery-form

Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var options = {

        target: "#output",
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: showResponse,
        timeout: 3000
    };

    // привязываем событие submit к форме
    $('#form').submit(function () {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });
    // ---- Форма -----
});

// вызов перед передачей данных
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    return true;
}

// вызов после получения ответа 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText) {}
```

Подключены jquery и jquery.form. В обработчике `.submit(fn)` fn возвращает false, как видно, однако форма отправляется 2 раза. Как предотвратить повторную отправку?

Comment: А что она должна возвращать, если в ней явно прописано `return false`?))

Comment: Этот самый false должен предотвращать работу браузера по умолчанию. То есть не отправлять форму. Вопрос в том, какого лешего форма отправляется дважды

Comment: не лучше ли для этих целей использовать event.preventDefault()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[читаем](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) до просветления.

Либо не вешаем событие на `$('#form').submit`

либо в

```
$('#form').submit(function () {
    //перебираем все елементы формы и отправляем c помощью $.post(...)
}
```

Comment: См. http://www.linkexchanger.su/2008/45.html Скрипт оттуда взял. ничего не менял. Там всё работает как нужно. 2 раза отправки нет.

Comment: ну и ? Там написано всё тоже самое что и на официальном сайте.

Откуда вы вообще $('#form').submit взяли ?